# How to get maven to find the FIRST 'latest' version in a list of repositories?

Tags: maven, version-control, versioning, nexus

I have a maven parent pom that specifies a long list of repositories.
In child poms we use version ranges to request the latest version.

Sometimes projects lag behind trunk, so maven begins resolving the absolute latest version, rather than the latest version from a particular branch repository.

How can I tell maven to find the latest version in order of precedence?
So
Check local m2.. empty.
Ok check our branch repo : yes found at 1.2.1
STOP do not check public and find that there's a later version at 1.2.2

Comment: Prevent using version ranges cause this leads to non reproducible builds. Furthermore don't define repositories in POM files they belong to settings.xml or better into the configuration of a repository manager.

Comment: I agree.. however this is not something we can change easily.. what I'm looking for is a workaround.. some sort of maven configuration that tells it to stop when it finds the first matching artifact in the repositories list.

Comment: No there is not such kind of configuration....

Comment: Your build must be clean and reproducible. What you're saying is completely preventing that and Maven won't let you get away with it. And frankly, I'm happy that it does: what you want to do would lead to a world of pain in the future.

Comment: I think I've found an acceptable answer.
One could override the RepositoryManagementMojo, but apparently the right thing to do is to use Nexus etc. to effectively manage resolution for you (because it's much more flexible than Maven).
Add both your trunk repository and your branch repositories to the same repository group, and then configure resolution within your binary repository. This means you only have one repo in your maven pom also.